# Installing node.js/npm on external hard drive (Mac OS Mojave)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, portability

So I want to install node.js on my external hard drive so I can do some batch processing on images for my website. I was following [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/) article and there's a section for converting images to webp with node. I've been trying to do that, but I keep having problems that I think are related to most of my files being on a 1tb external hard drive b/c my mac only has 250gb of space ($$ reasons). At the same time, I'm still confused about node.js and npm and how it all really works - as soon as I think I understand I find more info that puts me back at square one. I've really tried to do my own research re: errors that come up when installing node.js but it'd be really helpful if someone could simplify this process for me and help this 'lil noob who just wants to learn something new and more efficient.

tl;dr - My goal is to install node.js to process some images on an external hard drive on my mac and I want to do it smoothly and actually understand what's happening b/c the influx of information I'm getting from researching on my own is confusing me more than helping me :')

For reference, here's a link to a pic of what the terminal gives me after installing node.js and npm using this guide ([here](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-nodejs-tutorial-mac-os-x/)), and fixing an "no package.json found" error by running npm init and creating a package.json file. I'm currently following [this](https://dev.to/letsbsocial1/the-new-npm-audit-with-npm-6-2ipf) and [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities) to try and figure out what's wrong
(desc: terminal screenshot of a npm audit security report containing two moderate  severity memory exposure vulnerabilities) [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30NhH.png)

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! Is your actual project located on your internal HD? NPM will install all your dependencies in the project directory that you are in. So, unless your project is actually stored on your external drive, it'll be on your internal.

Comment: Thank you! My actual project is located on my external hard drive